# RequestBody in retrofit gets serialized by gson-converter

Tags: json, gson, converters, retrofit2

I would like to pass `RequestBody` as `@Body` parameter

After passing it into retrofit with `gson-converter` attached `RequestBody` is serialized into : `{}`

My current workaround is to use separate retrofit instance without any converters.

Since I would like to have only one retrofit instance my question is how to suppress `gson-converter` from serializing `RequestBody`

Comment: Have you tried `ScalarsConverterFactory` instead?

Comment: @BNK all the others responses from other endpoints are in json format so I need gson-converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I've found that this is a bug prior to '2.0.0-beta2`.